# What is the meaning of "Annotated Frame"?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Could anyone tell me what is the meaning of "Annotated Frame" (as seen in picture below)?

It is print screen of Call Stack in Visual Studio:
[image]

It is bothering me for years and I could not find answer yet.
I have googled, looked at ms-docs,  it many times , but no result ...

Comment: in very shallow terms an annotated frame is a stackframe having additional information beyond the function name/arguments[...]. The more in depth resource I could refer to is only [DkmStackWalkFrame.AnnotatedModule Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.debugger.callstack.dkmstackwalkframe.annotatedmodule?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#microsoft-visualstudio-debugger-callstack-dkmstackwalkframe-annotatedmodule).

Comment: => _If we have an annotated frame, specifies an optional module instance to associate with this frame. If present, the user will be able to load binaries or symbols for this module by right-clicking on this frame in the call stack window. This is NULL for non-annotated frames._

Comment: @DiegoD what do you think ?

Comment: @adamboss If I was more confident of what I've said in comments I made the answer myself :) I didn't just because I was not sure it was enough. Anyway it's good to have fulfilled questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Diego D said:

In very shallow terms an annotated frame is a stackframe having additional information beyond the function name/arguments[...]. The more in depth resource I could refer to is only [DkmStackWalkFrame.AnnotatedModule Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.debugger.callstack.dkmstackwalkframe.annotatedmodule?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#microsoft-visualstudio-debugger-callstack-dkmstackwalkframe-annotatedmodule).

If we have an annotated frame, specifies an optional module instance to associate with this frame. If present, the user will be able to load binaries or symbols for this module by right-clicking on this frame in the call stack window. This is NULL for non-annotated frames.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your expertise.

Comment: We However I have one additional question. 
 
Does annotated frame has something in common with frame with **no-instruction address** ? 
 
For example , in description of method **GetInstructionSymbol** 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.debugger.callstack.dkmstackwalkframe) 
it is written that like that: _"... the stack frame has no instruction address (annotated frame) ..."_ 

Thus based on the above mentioned MSDN note the first thought is that **no-instruction address** frame and **annotated frame** are the same. 
What do you think?