# Visual Studio - Annotated Frame - No-Instruction Address Frame

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

Does Annotated Frame in Visual Studio has something in common with frame with **no-instruction address** ?

For example , in description of method **GetInstructionSymbol** ([learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/…](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.debugger.callstack.dkmstackwalkframe)) it is written that like that: *"... the stack frame has no instruction address (annotated frame) ..."*
Thus based on the above mentioned MSDN note the first thought is that **no-instruction address** frame and **annotated frame** are the same. What do you think?

This question is a followup of: [What is the meaning of "Annotated Frame"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77805813/what-is-the-meaning-of-annotated-frame)

I did check MSDN documentation as mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Annotated Frame is no-instruction address frame.

Comment: Additionally , could you tell me if answer posted by Node Defender is correct: *"In very shallow terms an annotated frame is a stackframe having additional information beyond the function name/arguments[...]. The more in depth resource I could refer to is only DkmStackWalkFrame.AnnotatedModule Property. If we have an annotated frame, specifies an optional module instance to associate with this frame. If present, the user will be able to load binaries or symbols for this module by right-clicking on this frame in the call stack window. This is NULL for non-annotated frames."*

Comment: Node Defender posted this answer in __*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77805813/what-is-the-meaning-of-annotated-frame*__

Comment: I get the answer from GitHub Dotnet Api doc issues: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/9633.  For an authoritative answer to the question in your link, I suggest asking on the GitHub dotnet doc.

Comment: One more time thank you. I did not find this GitHub discussion before.